# phpMyAdmin server description instead of hostname

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed phpMyAdmin 4.4.8 (latest version) and I configured some MySQL host I can connect to.

Servers are listed with the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] value in the server list and I cannot find out a way to configure a "description string" in the phpMyAdmin configuration file.

I know I could configure a DNS or a /etc/hosts entry to assign a custom name to the servers, but I wish to use a more understandable description (like "Testing server" or "Production server").

Do you know a way to configure this in phpMyAdmin?

Thank you very much!

Bye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try set `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']`

> `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']`
>
> Type:   **string**
>     Default value:  ''
>
> Only useful when using phpMyAdmin with multiple server entries. If set, this string will be displayed instead of the hostname in the
>   pull-down menu on the main page. This can be useful if you want to
>   show only certain databases on your system, for example. For HTTP
>   auth, all non-US-ASCII characters will be stripped.

Ref: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#server-connection-settings

Comment: Thank you very much Federico! I didn't see that configuration variable!